# FrameEventsArgs Time member variable is not returning rational values when I debug

Tags: xamarin.android

When I put a breakpoint in the OnRenderFrame function and inspect the FrameEventsArgs parameter I get really large numbers for FrameEventsArgs.Time.

Numbers like 1.75842543717402E+132 which is ridiculously large. I occasionally get ridiculously small numbers too.

If I create the default GL app with monodevelop and debug it without changing anything the value is always 3.46247528645812E-317.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot. I guess I could blame the Xamarin people for passing the FrameEventsArgs class as a parameter to OnRenderFrame but I wont.

OnUpdateFrame gets a valid FrameEventsArgs with the Time variable properly set.